# Cannot find hadith reference

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I read online: "The Prophet peace be upon him also said: "Give charity without delay, for it stands in the way of calamity." - Al-Tirmidhi, Hadith 589

However, when I go to https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/

I cannot find this hadith anywhere. I searched in multiple apps on google store as well, no luck. Please find the correct reference for me. Thanks.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model I recommend you to take our [tour] and check our [help]. As to your question could you share the link where you have read this hadith?

Comment: https://www.islamawareness.net/Hadith/htopic_charity.html

Comment: https://www.zakat.org/en/charitible-prophet-charity-hadith/

Comment: https://www.interpal.org/20160616-give-charity-without-delay-for-it-stands-in-the-way-of-calamity/

Comment: I have given 3 websites, however, if you search on the web, so many links come up. I however could not find it anywhere in Sunan Tirhmidhi. 

https://www.islamawareness.net/Hadith/htopic_charity.html
https://www.zakat.org/en/charitible-prophet-charity-hadith/
https://www.interpal.org/20160616-give-charity-without-delay-for-it-stands-in-the-way-of-calamity/

JazakALLAH Khail

Comment: https://dorar.net/hadith/search?q=باكروا+صدقة&st=w&xclude=&page=1

Comment: Thanks for the links but none of them reveal anything helpful about this hadith (for example a rawy or chapter or so) while the link of @ButarekHd (who should consider answering the question) shows that a similar hadith is falsely referred to the book of imam at-Tirmidhi and it is mentioned in a book about fabricated ahadith and is narrated on the authority of Anas ibn Malik ad 'Ali ibn abi Talib.

Comment: If you google this hadith, you get dozens of websites referencing this from Imam Tirmidhi. Thanks for clarifying that this is fabricated. @Medi1Saif

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest hadith I can find is this:

> إن الصدقة لتطفئ غضب الرب وتدفع ميتة السوء
>
> Indeed charity extinguishes the Lord's anger and it protects against
>   the evil death.

The reference for it is:

جامع الترمذي , كتاب الزكاة, باب ما جاء في فضل الصدقة

Jami` at-Tirmidhi , The Book on Zakat , Chapter: What Has Been Related About The Virtue Of Charity

https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/7/48

Answer (score 3):

They may be referring to the less well known Tirmidhi (Abu Abdullah Muhammad bin Ali Al-Hakim At-Tirmidhi Al-Khurasani Al-Hanafi) or one of the famous Tirmidhi's (Abu Isa Muhammad bin Isa bin Sawrah Ad-Dahak As-Sulami At-Tirmidhi) less well known books as he authored many. At any rate, this Hadith does not occur in the Sunan (Jami) of At-Tirmidhi and it is the burden of the narrator to provide its specific location as the burden of proof is upon the claimant. Try contacting the organization directly for clarity.